# Як перекласти "robotic tortoises"?

Tags: переклад

Цікавить переклад словосполучення "robotic tortoises", де "robotic" перекладається як "автоматичний", "саморушний", "механічний" (джерело - [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/robotic)) та "роботизований" (джерело - Гугл перекладач, і саме цей варіант найближчий до того, який потрібний"), а "tortoises" - це "черепаха" (однак, замість цього іменика може бути будь-який інший, наприклад "dog" - "собака", чи "spider" - "павук").

Отож винкла проблема який переклад буде найкращий - "робот-черепаха", "роботизована черепаха" (однак, слова "роботизований" немає в СУМі), "робо-черепаха" (проте, не знайшов схожих прикладів в українській мові, а лише в російській, наприклад "[робо-жук](http://ru.spyro.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BA)").

Пошук в Гуглі видає "робот-черепаха", але цікавить чи можливі ще й інші варіанти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Робот-черепаха** — робот, що має якісь ознаки черепахи.

  При цьому бути повноцінною черепахою йому необов'язково, достатньо мати лише деякі ознаки / чимось нагадувати черепаху. Але язик має повертатися назвати його роботом. Приклад:
  [image: Робот із 6 ногами, що чимось може нагадувати черепаху]

  Практично те саме — **черепахоподібний робот**.
- **Черепаха-робот** — черепаха, що має якісь ознаки робота.

  При цьому бути повноцінним роботом їй необов'язково, достатньо мати лише деякі ознаки / чимось нагадувати робота. Але язик має повертатися назвати її черепахою.

  Часткові випадки:

  - **роботизована черепаха** — черепаха, якій *штучно надали* якісь ознаки робота (можливо, деякі органи замінили штучними, додали якісь роботичні компоненти абощо; порівняти: *механізована черепаха*);
  - **роботоподібна черепаха** — черепаха, *в цілому* подібна до робота (найімовірніше, це вживатиметься в переносному сенсі, наприклад, щоб підкреслити незвичну зовнішність або незвичну поведінку звичайної живої черепахи, про таку ймовірніше напишуть *черепаха-«робот»*, а не *черепаха-робот*).

Залежно від того, що мається на увазі в оригіналі, можуть підійти ті чи інші варіанти. Або відразу декілька — наприклад, якщо мова про [щось таке](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVytLJpPtSs) (робот, що повністю імітує зовнішній вигляд черепахи — настільки, що це вводить в оману живих черепах), то це можна назвати і *роботом-черепахою* чи *черепахоподібним роботом* (акцентуючи увагу на тому, що це робот), і *черепахою-роботом* чи *роботизованою черепахою* (акцентуючи увагу на точності вподібнення до черепахи, що це «майже» черепаха).

**Робочерепаха** — жаргонна назва. Разом з тим слово *роботизований* є в [«Словниках України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) й [«Українсько-англійському словнику з радіоелектроніки» Б. Рицаря, Л. Сніцарука й Р. Мисака 2015 року](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=16&highlight=on), а [утворення слів на *-подібний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/podibnyj) і [приєднання прикладки через дефіс](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par27p2) не суперечать традиціям українського словотвору.